# Migrating from Shopify: Manual or Migration Tools?

Tags: magento2, data-migration

The company I work at has been using Shopify for about 3 years. Due to expanding business requirements, we want to migrate to Magento 2. With Shopify, the site is running with workarounds so it has stability issues.

I found several tools that provide data migration services - LitExtension, Cart2Cart, etc. Since they cost money, I'm thinking if it's more practical to have certain entities (e.g. customers, orders) migrated with the tool and others (e.g. products) done manually.

**Question: Is there any known issue whereby the automated and manually migrated data fail to link to each other?**

My assumption is that regardless of migration method of each entity, when in Magento, I'm able to see Customer A (auto migrate) purchased Product B (manual import). Is that assumption true?

Same goes if all products/customers/orders are manually migrated; is it correct that the data link will be retained? I would like to clarify on this for analysis and reporting purposes.